# Retrieving the url or route path within a Template

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am currently using Iron Router. In my Template file I am retrieving the url through

```
var url = Router.current().url
```

or

```
var url = Router.current().originalUrl
```

These returns the current path without the protocol and hostname.

```
/your/current/path
```

However, when you refresh the page (browser refresh), the same methods return the whole url (protocol, hostname and path).

```
http://localhost:3000/your/current/path
```

How do I retrieve the whole url or route path reliably?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Iron.Location object for that here are few property that you can use

```
Iron.Location.get().rootUrl  --> 'http://localhost:3000'
Iron.Location.get().path --> '/your/current/path'
Iron.Location.get().port --> 3000
Iron.Location.get().protocol --> 'http:'
Iron.Location.get().queryObject ---> return query object
Iron.Location.get().hostname --> 'localhost'
Iron.Location.get().host --> 'localhost:3000'

Meteor.absoluteUrl() will give the root url as well.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do I import `Iron`?

Comment: Are you using meteor 1.3 ?

Comment: Answering my own question `import { Iron } from 'meteor/iron:core';`

Comment: Yeah that's cool, this is how you can import that. It mean you are using 1.3.

Comment: I tried running all of the commands you mentioned within 2 use cases:
1) Coming from a different page within the website, all of the commands return empty except for `Iron.Location.get().path`
2) When the web page is refreshed, all of the commands return a value. 
To answer my question, which one is reliable, only `Iron.Location.get().path` is

Comment: If some of commands are return empty then you can user autorun.

Comment: I am running them in a button click event

Comment: That's always works for me, You can you please check Iron.Location.get() in console, does have all the property or not ?